# What is a word, or phrase, for something that is so obscure that you no longer want to do it?

Tags: phrases, expressions

My coworkers and I are using an internal request site and we are trying to figure out the correct word, phrase, or expression for our feelings.  The site, and it's instructions, are so obscure that it takes enough time to just completely turn you off to using it, almost to the point of disgust.

Is there a word or phrase that accurately represents this?

*EDIT*: Here is an example:

I go to some webpage, www.usethistool.com.  It is a form for requesting new software to be installed on my machine.  There is no button or link that says: "Order software here" instead there is a link that says "View Cart".  Once you click that, there is another link that says, "Add to Cart".  That brings you to a form with a few fields, but nowhere to attach files.  After you click another "Add Cart" button at the bottom, you go to another page where you can add attachments.  You continue this button clicking for a few more pages until finally it is "in your cart" and ready to be serviced.

The whole thing took an obscene amount of time and I would've much rather climbed up and down 5 flights of stair to go to different offices, if need be.  The experience left us confused, unclear, and border-line afraid to use it again.

Comment: Can you give an example?  Without more context, the best word that pops into my head is *arcane*.

Comment: Maybe off-putting:provoking uneasiness, dislike, annoyance, or repugnance. Also 'intricate': solvable or comprehensible only with painstaking effort.

Comment: user-hostile?..

Comment: I like repugnance, but it borders to much on a feeling of upheaval instead of disdain.  Additionally, I need to capture that thought of obscurity being the driving force.

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective to describe the software, a noun to refer to it by, the feeling it instils in you, or something else entirely?

Comment: I am looking for either the feeling it instills in me or a word to describe the entire event.  Something like: the process was so obscure that I shudder at the idea of having to do it again.    The answer from @dnagirl is probably about as close as it is going to get it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*byzantine* can be used to describe processes that are convoluted, complicated and seemingly without logic.

> Ordering software was such a byzantine process that I'm not sure I
>   could successfully repeat it.

Comment: I'm really liking this one, let me see if anything else pops up before I confirm it.

Comment: @JasonWilczak: glad you like it.  *rigmarole* is an nice noun for the same kind of thing, if you need one.

Comment: Thanks @dnagirl, I feel like byzantine is just the word for this!

Answer (score 1):

***[time-consuming](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20consuming)*** ,adj.- of a task that takes time and patience
 - wasteful of time

> A relatively **great or greater** than average duration or passage of time
>   or a duration as specified

[E.g.:](http://www.economist.com/news/americas/21635520-president-proposes-laws-fight-crime-mexicans-want-more-justicia)

- Resolving complaints through the legal system is so costly and *time-consuming* that most    people do not bother
- After fermenting the beans—a *time-consuming* step that chocolate producers often skip—Toth and his partners dry, roast, de-shell and grind each batch by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe such a process as "Overly-***[convoluted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/convoluted)***", although this might not get across the point of not wanting to do it again, or to the point of disgust:

> extremely complex and difficult to follow

In context you could say something along the lines of:

> I didn't install the software as the process was horrendously convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

> **discouraging** (adj) - depriving of *confidence* or *hope* or *enthusiasm* and hence often deterring action. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discouraging)

Researchers were discouraged by the problem's magnitude

Comment: This fits part of the bill but it doesn't reign in the fact that it is discouraging because of its obscurity.

Comment: @JasonWilczak It's the best I could come up with.

Comment: I agree, discouraging is probably the right choice here.  Let me see if anything else comes up, or I'll take this one.